# Threejs 2000 textures bottleneck

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I've been playing around with three.js a couple of months now. Recenlty we started a three.js app - project which is a 3d webgl product catalogue(imagine plane with the product image as a texture 512x512), storing base64 images into browser indexeddb and on app load creates the product catalogue.

However we have performance issues, imagine that a category of products might have 100 products or even more and the total number of products could be up to 10000.

On each category we present our models(planes) in a specific way. Because the app should offer a nice user experience everything is being pre-loaded, textures are generated before the app starts and saved in memory. Here is where the issue starts...

At the moment on a hardware with a 4gb of ram and an on-board gpu that shares memory with cpu results in chrome crash. Also each model can be dragged by the user by touch events.

On the other hand we tried loading textures on demand but this is a big impact for user experience, it might freeze the app for 1-2 secs.

At the moment materials are being created for each product without any textures. Textures are stored on a different object based on product id, and when each category loads we assign the texture to each model. Also we dispose textures from materials that are no longer visible.

My issue is that having to store 2000 textures is not memory efficient and causes chrome to crash on low badget hardware. On the other hand if I load textures on demand user experience freezes for a couple of seconds...

Keep in mind that each model is draggable by user touch.

I don't face any coding problems so there is no point to show any code unless you 'd like to see something. My main concern is architectural.

If there is a more performant way to implement such an app... I've thought of particle systems, but having a different texture for each particle would result in the same result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to investigate why exactly your loading process is freezing the app for *a few seconds*, this sounds way too long.

**Memory**

Consider the size of your data, assuming that your 512x512 textures are *only* around 256kb in size each, for 2000 textures you're still trying to store 500MB (+ ~33% base64 overhead) of data in indexedDB which is currently limited to 5MB. So you'll have to load the textures on demand either way.

**Texture atlas / Megatextures:**

Using megatextures/a texture atlas will not be a feasible approach here. WebGL does not support the features necessary to impliment this in a memory efficient way. You would need to allocate a texture in maximum texture size(between 8k and 16k) and then tile your textures into it, keeping track of what textures are currently used so that you may update arbitrary parts of the atlas with new, required textures. Once you run out of atlas tiles you need to allocate a new atlas texture at maximum size and this is where you'll get real hiccups and crashes as you cant query how much GPU memory is available.

**Implementing an adaptive loading queue:**

```
var textureQueue = [];
// on visible
if (loadedTextures[textureID])
    return object.texture = loadedTextures[textureID];

textureQueue.push(textureID);
object.texture = loadingTexture;

// each update
var
    startLoading = window.performance.now(),
    currentTime = startLoading,
    loadID
;
while(
    currentTime - startLoading < 10/*ms*/ &&
    loadID = textureQueue.shift()
) {
    /** load and assign texture here **/
    currentTime = window.performance.now();
}
```

Comment: The problem as far as I can see is that once you have to show 100 products on demand,  generating 100 textures (retrieve base64 strings -> create new Image() -> Create Texture(image) ) is halting the system. And I'm pretty sure it's because of the too frequent data passing to the gpu. I was also wondering about megatextures...

Comment: Also yes I agree the data size is too much

Comment: You dont have to create them all within one frame have you? I'll update my answer in terms of megatextures in a moment.

Comment: hmmm What you said "You dont have to create them all within one frame have you?" got me thinking... So if I break down the products into chunks lets say 10 per frame or something like that, might actually work dont you think ?

Comment: Yes, just assign a "loading" texture to everything that needs to be loaded. Then load the textures in batches, you may even profile this on the fly: *load as many textures as you can within Xms*, then postpone the following ones to the next frame and repeat. Essentially build a loading queue that is processed for a specified amount of time every frame.

Comment: I like this approach and I believe it's the only way from w/e I've seen so far. thnx

Comment: @Syd I've added some code to show the adaptive loading queue.

Comment: I'm curious about your comment that megatextures can't be implemented in WebGL. Megatextures have been around for 15-20+ years, long before the features WebGL supports. Maybe you have a different definition of megatextures? Google Maps pretty much implements this.

Comment: @gman I didn't mean to say they're not implementable, sure they are. Imho they're just not suitable for this usecase as with WebGL one can not dynamically allocate parts of them using things like [sparse textures/partially resident textures](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/sparse_texture.txt). Resulting in the above mentioned hiccups / problems when allocating a new megatexture during runtime. They're sure a great *and feasible* way to speed up rendering(a lot) in cases where one knows about the amount of textures to be loaded upfront.

Comment: @LJ I'm would megatextures be suitable for rendering panorama photos on spheres? In this case you know how many textures you need upfront. Could you point me to some recent resources about this technique for WebGL?